# Posting Special Characters in Python Requests Body

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, python-requests

I am trying to post a body that has an accented character using the requests library in Python 3. I've tried all sorts of combinations of encodings with no such luck.

My request:

```
import requests
requests.post('http://localhost:9999/post',  data='é')
```

My server:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/post", methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    print(request.stream.read())
    return request.data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

I would expect to see the server print out the proper accented character, but instead I get the byte code `b'\xe9'` Ideally, I'd like to adjust the request, not the server, which is just used for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/716#issuecomment-19686863) is helpful to you.
`request.data` returns bytes instead of unicode.
The linked issue on GitHub says to use `request.get_data()` instead of `request.data` as it provides an `as_text` parameter you can use to get unicode instead of bytes.